# Import Sharepoint 2010 BDCM file in a SharePoint 2013 environment

Tags: 2010, 2013, bdc-model, bdc

I was wondering if it's possible to import a BDCM file exported from SharePoint 2010 in a Sharepoint 2013 environment ?

Is the file format identical ?

Thank you